# ReactReduxSocketMiddleware is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, redux, react-redux

I'm using react-redux-socket and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _client.ReactReduxSocketMiddleware) is not a function

Then I proceed to check in node_modules/react-redux-socket/client/index.js then saw it exports ReactActionSocketMiddleware and MakeSocketAction only.
So I tried importing ReactActionSocketMiddleware instead of ReactReduxSocketMiddleware.
It got rid of the error but nothing is really working. I wonder if I'm missing something.

here's my code:

### server.js

```
import ioActionHandler from 'react-redux-socket/server';
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = socket(http);
const socketHandler = function(action, { dispatch, broadcast, socket }) {
  console.log('to server, from', socket.id);
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TEST':
      console.log('server_test');
      dispatch({ type: 'CLIENT_TEST', payload: action.payload });
      break;
  }
}
ioActionHandler(io, socketHandler);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
http.listen(port,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

### reducer-test.js

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CLIENT_TEST':
                console.log('client_test');
                return action.payload;
                break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

### action.js

```
// this gets called from my component container when I click a button then I pass this.prop.dispatch
import { MakeSocketAction } from 'react-redux-socket/client'

export function test(dispatch) {
    console.log('dispatch action');
    dispatch( MakeSocketAction({ type: 'TEST', payload: 'test' }));
}
```

Comment: I run into a similar issue but after checking the sample code for this npm package, I got mine to work perfectly well.   

https://github.com/trouve-antoine/react-redux-socket/tree/master/samples/chat